GraphQL converts nullable long to required long
In my app I am using a SetNullableValueInput class to make my properties be resetable in a mutation:
public class SetNullableValueInput<T> where T : notnull
{
    public T? Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator SetValueInput<T?>?(SetNullableValueInput<T>? value)
    {
        return value == null ? null : new SetValueInput<T?> { Value = value.Value };
    }
}

public class SetValueInput<TValue>
{
    public required TValue Value { get; set; }
}

My input for my mutation is defined like this:
public class EditInputType
{
    public SetNullableValueInput<long>? MyData { get; set; }
}

This is my mutation call in my playground:
mutation {
  myMutation(input: { myData: {value: 1}}) {
      myData
  }
}

Following calls work:
input: { myData: {value: 1}}
input: { myData: null}
When I try this, I get an error which says "Expected value of type Long!, found null".
input: { myData: {value: null}}
Edit:
If I change my input type from SetNullableValueInput<long>? to SetNullableValueInput<string>?, everything works fine. Does HotChocolate handle simple data types differently?
